# Copying files from a damaged Mac – Finder or CCC?

Tags: macos, macbook-pro, hard-drive, backup

I have a Mac which can't boot up (it sees the prohibitory sign when it's turned on). I am going to do a clean reinstall of macOS on it. I want to keep the data somewhere, of course, so I don't lose all my files.

Since the Mac is damaged, do I need to make a clone of the drive (using Carbon Copy Cloner) or will a simply copy and paste of the drive to the target drive from the Finder do? I don't need the copied data to form a bootable drive, as it is damaged anyway. I just want to keep the personal files and folders intact, and perhaps the applications as well so I know what I had installed on the drive.

P.S. I'd rather not use CCC or any external programs *if that's possible*. I'm running macOS off a USB drive and it's incredibly slow, so third-party software is merely a hindrance.

Comment: Although I've posted an answer to your question, as an aside have you actually tried any troubleshooting for the _damaged Mac_ issue you have? You may be able to resolve that rather than doing the clean install.

Comment: Yeah, I tried nearly everything! It's pretty much bricked at this point. Thanks for the suggestion though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have a functioning copy of macOS running from a USB you can still set up Time Machine to backup your internal drive to the target drive. This would be your best option to ensure you're capturing a full backup, alhough of course the first backup will take quite some time. However, just copying and pasting all your data would also take some time.

You could just do a copy and paste within Finder from your internal drive to target drive, but you do risk missing data that you may not want to lose. For example, if you use the default macOS Mail app, all the emails etc are stored in the User's library folder.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! About the User library folder – if I did a copy and paste, it wouldn't be copied over? Are hidden files not copied over? Then I might just use TM or CCC.

Comment: Just to clarify, my main concern is that most people won't think to copy the User library folder (either it's hidden so they don't know about it) or they overlook it. However, you can copy this across manually (although depending on your setup you may be prompted for an Admin password). Either way, as long as you can see the User library folder (i.e. it's not hidden) you should be able to copy it and the OS will generate an error if there's anything it won't let you copy, so you'll know about it.

Comment: However, my suggestion would still be to use TM, especially if you're wanting to reinstall the same apps again, as it will make that process a lot easier for you after the fresh install.

Comment: All right, thank you again very much for the help!

Comment: If your disk is corrupted I think time machine will fail

Comment: @Mark If that does happen, then it's good that the OP knows the disk is corrupted, and it's another reason to use TM. I've seen many backup/imaging programs make a copy of a corrupted drive that resulted in the user thinking they had a backup they didn't actually have. This way the OP can take other steps to try and save whatever they can, and there's nothing stopping them from doing a manual copy and paste later if TM fails (i.e. before trying to do a fresh install).

Comment: CCC and rsync will tell the user that files are corrupt but will continue

Comment: I'm not actually disagreeing with you :) It's just that the OP did specifically say, _"I'd rather not use CCC or any external programs if that's possible."_ and from my point of view using TM is still preferable to doing a manual copy and paste (at least for most users).

Answer (score 1):

Using disk Utility’s restore function, you can clone a drive. It is a built in app in the utilities folder inside of the applications folder.